# I am trying to make a dropdown sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown sidebar menu.

please see the image attached

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsvzQ.png

I need the section to be open on a desktop view and close in mobile view.

what is the best way to achieve this?

I am trying to use the code in the following link.

https://codepen.io/gregsaxton/pen/eoWGxL

```
<ul class="m-d expand-list">
<li data-md-content="200">
    <label name="tab" for="tab1" tabindex="-1" class="tab_lab" role="tab">Product Description</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="tab" id="tab1" tabindex="0" />
    <span class="open-close-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to Brackets, a modern open-source code editor that understands web design. It's a lightweight,
        yet powerful, code editor that blends visual tools into the editor so you get the right amount of help
        when you want it.
    </div>
</li>
<li data-md-content="300">
        <label name="tab" for="tab2" tabindex="-1" class="tab_lab" role="tab">Specifications</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tab" id="tab2" tabindex="0" />
        <span class="open-close-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
        <div class="content">
            <em>Brackets is a different type of editor.</em>
        Brackets has some unique features like Quick Edit, Live Preview and others that you may not find in other
        editors. Brackets is written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. That means that most of you using Brackets
        have the skills necessary to modify and extend the editor. In fact, we use Brackets every day to build
        Brackets. To learn more about how to use the key features, read on.
    </div>
</li>
<li data-md-content="600">
        <label name="tab" for="tab3" tabindex="-1" class="tab_lab" role="tab">Shipping &amp; Returns</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tab" id="tab3" tabindex="0" />
        <span class="open-close-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
  <div class="content">
            <h3>Projects in Brackets</h3>
    <p>
        In order to edit your own code using Brackets, you can just open the folder containing your files.
        Brackets treats the currently open folder as a "project"; features like Code Hints, Live Preview and
        Quick Edit only use files within the currently open folder.
    </p>
    <samp>
        Once you're ready to get out of this sample project and edit your own code, you can use the dropdown
        in the left sidebar to switch folders. Right now, the dropdown says "Getting Started" - that's the
        folder containing the file you're looking at right now. Click on the dropdown and choose "Open Folder…"
        to open your own folder.
        You can also use the dropdown later to switch back to folders you've opened previously, including this
        sample project.
    </samp>
        </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: I don't see any image but you can use [media-query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. As this does not sound like anything new: have you tried to check how other websites solved this problem?

Comment: Please, specify the language you use and show your code what you have already done

Comment: I am trying to make something like this.https://www.codehim.com/demo/jquery-vertical-sidenav-accordeon/#  but the dropdowns should be open on the desktop and closed on mobile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**By using two ways you can do this**

1. using javascript to detect device (desktop / mobile) then with a if condition u can close or open the section onload.
2. using css media query to detect screen size and open or close the section onload.

**example** : for option 2

```
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}
```